# "NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found." - flutter audioplayers on web debugging

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to play a sound when a button is clicked, and decided to use the "audioplayers" library for it. The problem is that when I run my app on the well I get this weird error-

```
Error: NotSupportedError: Failed to load because no supported source was found.
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:5076:12)
    at Object._rethrow (http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:40477:16)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:40473:13)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:40330:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:40336:13)
    at http://localhost:49201/dart_sdk.js:35811:9
```

I dont't really know why this is happening. I'll try testing this on an emulator and see how it goes. But for now here's the code-

Here's the code-

```
class _PopScreenState extends State<PopScreen> {
  late String currentPath;
  AudioCache player = new AudioCache();      //relevant

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentPath = normalPaths[widget.id];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: animalColorThemes[widget.id],
          title: Text(
            animalData[widget.id][0],
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (e) {
            player.play("assets/pop1.mp3");           //relevant
            setState(() {
              currentPath = activePaths[widget.id];
            });
          },
          onTapUp: (e) {
            setState(() {
              currentPath = normalPaths[widget.id];
            });
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: AssetImage(
                      currentPath,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you have to check you're **pubspec.yaml** file and register assets folder on it like this:

```
flutter:    
        assets:
                - assets/audio/
```

be careful about space in this file.
then you can use this library too: [audio player](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

the second cuase  this error is spelling you file name.